# How do I use this Encrypt 5.0.0 package properly?

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

***Problem***

Trying to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) for encryption. I am using (or attempting to use) asymmetric RSA.

The documentation says to use secure-random command line. I have no idea how to do this. I know this is a real noob trouble but this is uncharted territory for me.

Also, I'm sure this has something to do with needing to copy/paste public.pem & private.pem as well as the corresponding keys in the files. I used the actual example keys from the package github example. But i'm sure these are supposed to be generated on my end.

***Question***

How do I use the secure-random command line and does this have anything to do with generating the public/private key files?

The documentation is vague so any help for a noob in this area would be appreciated :)

Comment: For **symmetric encryption** you need (at best) a randomly generated key, the "secure-random command line" is just an example how to generate such a random key. For **asymmetric encryption** (e.g. RSA) you need a **key pair** and the Encrypt package seems not to have a built-in RSA keypair generator.

Comment: Okay then I assume I can use any good old generator. But would still be good to know how to use this as a command line. Because I’ve run into this trouble before. Is there a simple tutorial for dart command line use? I am having trouble finding one.